# Why the two event call the same method in angular9.0.3, target.value is not the same?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: ]([![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2TV2.png))

#### This's the html code

```
<input class="edit" (keydown.escape)="cancelSave($event)" (blur)="saveTodo(item, $event)"
                 (keydown.enter)="saveTodo(item, $event)" [value]="currentEdit.title">
```

#### This's the invoke methed

```
  public saveTodo(item: CurrentTodo, event): void {
    item.title = event.target.value;
    this.currentEdit = this.NULL_TODO;
  }
```

#### When the (keydown.enter) event is triggered

```
item.title = event.target.value;
print(event.target.value) // output : hello
```

#### When the (blur) event is triggered

```
item.title = event.target.value;
print(event.target.value) // output : ''
```

I expected it should be the same twice, I was frustrated,
This will cause the results of the two saves to be completely different,
How should I solve it?
Looking forward to your answer, thanks

#### This is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttmmfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: can you please reproduce?, because i have tried using your code it is working fine look at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2xsam

Comment: This is the stackblitz link   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttmmfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The problem occurs when I try to modify double-click the task item and press Enter to confirm
Can be viewed through the console, (event.target.value) print results are inconsistent

Comment: I tried to pass direct value like : `<input #toDo class="edit" (keydown.escape)="cancelSave($event)" (blur)="saveTodo(item, toDo.value)" (keydown.enter)="saveTodo(item, toDo.value)" [value]="currentEdit.title">`, but still it's the same.

Comment: Yes, you can call it like this, but after calling it in my example, the value of (event.target.value) is automatically assigned to the empty string

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, this issue can now be resolved.
I bound (currentEdit.title) in the HTML, but cleared it in the method, so I couldn't get the value the second time